# The base of an isosceles triangle; given leg and radius of circumcircle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

> An isosceles triangle $\triangle ABC$ is given with leg $AC=5$ and $R=\dfrac{25}{6}$ of the circumcircle. Find the base of the triangle.

[image]

This was my first sketch. The triangles $AHC$ and $OMC$ are similar, so $\dfrac{CH}{CM}=\dfrac{AC}{CO} \Leftrightarrow \dfrac{CO+OH}{CM}=\dfrac{AC}{CO}.$ When I plug with the values, I get a negative number for $OH$. I realised that this is possible if the triangle is obtuse. How should I notice this from the beginning? I have not studied trigonometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in the standard notation  $$\frac{abc}{4S}=R,$$ we obtain:
$$\frac{5\cdot5\cdot c}{4\cdot\frac{c\sqrt{25-\frac{c^2}{4}}}{2}}=\frac{25}{6}$$ or
$$\sqrt{25-\frac{c^2}{4}}=3,$$
which gives $$c=8.$$

We'll prove that $$\frac{abc}{4S}=R.$$

Indeed, let $\Phi$ be our circle and $CO\cap\Phi=\{C,D\}$.

Thus, $$\Delta ACH\sim\Delta DCB,$$ which gives
$$\frac{CH}{BC}=\frac{AC}{CD}$$ or
$$\frac{CH}{a}=\frac{b}{2R}$$ or
$$CH=\frac{ab}{2R}.$$
Id est, $$\frac{abc}{4S}=\frac{abc}{4\cdot\frac{c\cdot\frac{ab}{2R}}{2}}=R.$$

Comment: Thank you for the response!

Comment: @LY You are welcome!

Comment: Which is the fastest way to solve the equation for $c$?

Comment: Thank you again! You have helped me so many times and I really appreciate this. Can I ask you something in a chat room?

Comment: @LYI OK. Ask your question

Comment: Thank you for the opportunity! Are you a math teacher or you just love solving math problems?

Comment: I am teacher and I like to solve math problems.

Comment: In a university?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108054/discussion-between-michael-rozenberg-and-lyi).

Answer (score 1):

For an acute triangle where the two shortest sides are $a$ and $b$, the inradius is $r$, and the circumradius is $R$, the inequality $R+r < \frac{a+b}{2}$ is satisfied. So in this case, if the triangle were acute, you would need $\frac{25}{6} + r < \frac{5+5}{2}$, i.e. $r < \frac{5}{6}$, which is really small, and you can see from the diagram that it's quite unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, OH is positive if the base AB is below the horizontal diameter line, and negative if the base is above. If AB happens to be the diameter, then AC = $\sqrt2$R.

Thus, you may compare the given AC and R to determine beforehand.

Comment: Thank you for the response! By "the horizantal diameter line" I should understand that which is parallel to $AB$, right?

Comment: @LYI - that’s correct

Comment: I am trying to understand what you mean and I would be very grateful if you help me with this. What do you mean that a segment is negative?

Comment: And we can compare $AC$ and $R$. So, $AC>R$ and what does this mean?

Comment: @LYI - in your derivation, you define CH = CO+ OH = R + OH. Then, if AB is above O, you have CH < R and OH = CH - R < 0, hence negative